# Ethereum geth reset the block to 0 again after i restarted my pc

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

Everything run well when i restarted running command "geth" for my local private network. but when i restarted my pc and run the geth command again, the block reset to 0 again.

Here is my code to init the geth from configuration in my genesis.json:

```
geth --datadir "/PATH_TO_NODE/" init /PATH_TO/genesis.json
```

And then i run my geth node with command:

```
geth --identity "node01" --http --http.port "8000" --http.corsdomain "*" --datadir "/PATH_TO_NODE/" --nodiscover --http.api "eth,net,web3,personal,miner,admin" --networkid 1900 --allow-insecure-unlock
```

when i rerun the command above there is no problem, it will continuing the block that already there. But it will be resetting to the 0 again when i restart my PC. Is it intended or not?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you've ran your geth node with a different network ID (--networkid 1900) rather than the default which is hardcoded as 1 and will have been used when you ran your first command (without the flag above). Every time you do this it resets the chain data. Also afaik, putting network ID in the genesis doesn't actually change anything. The only ways to change it are to a) hardcode it in the codebase or use the flag.